# Error while binding the selected value with DevExtreme and KnockOut

Tags: javascript, mobile, knockout.js, devexpress, devextreme

I trying to develop a little app.

I have made a login view and it works, I am able to bind the data written by the user. After this, I show two select box. The first is binded with a list (correctly) and the second has to be bind with a list populated after a value is selected from the first.

I'm not able to read the value selected from the first list.

I have this html:

```
<div class="dx-fieldset">
            <div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">Rete</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value"
                     data-bind="dxLookup: { dataSource: is_retistiSource, value: rete, displayExpr: 'NOME', title: 'Retisti associati', placeholder: 'Selezionare rete',
                                            onSelectionChanged:setRete }" />
            </div>

            <div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">Impianto</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value" 
                     data-bind="dxLookup: { dataSource: is_impiantiSource, value: impianto, displayExpr: 'NOME', title: 'Impianti associati', placeholder: 'Selezionare impianto' }" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this javascript:

```
OverviewAPP.afterLogin = function (params) {
    var isReady = $.Deferred();
    var viewModel = {
        rete: ko.observable(""),
        impianto: ko.observable(""),
        is_retistiSource: OverviewAPP.listaReti,
        is_impiantiSource: OverviewAPP.listaImpianti,
        setRete: function () {
            console.log(viewModel.rete);
            var nRetisti = OverviewAPP.listaRetiImpianti.length;
            for (i = 0; i < nRetisti; i++) {
                if (OverviewAPP.listaRetiImpianti[i]["retista"]["NOME"] == this.rete)
                {
                    OverviewAPP.listaImpianti = listaRetiImpianti[i]["listaImpianti"];
                    break;
                }
            }
            is_impiantiSource = OverviewAPP.listaImpianti;
        },
        close: function () {
            OverviewAPP.app.back();
        }
    };
    return viewModel;
};
```

In the setRete function, with the line "console.log(viewModel.rete);", I see this output:

```
d(){if(0<arguments.length)return d.Wa(c,arguments[0])&&(d.X(),c=arguments[0],d.W()),this;a.k.Ob(d);return c}
```

Why? How can I bind and read the selected value?

**UPDATE**:  I've done in this way, it works:

```
setRete: function (e) {
            OverviewAPP.IDrete = e.value;
            var nRetisti = OverviewAPP.listaRetiImpianti.length;
            for (i = 0; i < nRetisti; i++) {
                if (OverviewAPP.listaRetiImpianti[i]["retista"]["NOME"] == e.value["NOME"])
                {
                   OverviewAPP.listaImpianti = OverviewAPP.listaRetiImpianti[i]["listaImpianti"];
                    break;
                }
            }
            //ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        },
```

But I don't know how update my second list, "is_impiantiSource".

Comment: observables are setter/getter functions. You probably want `console.log(viewModel.rete())`

Comment: @RoyJ thanks for the comment. Meanwhile, I've done it in another way and it works. Can you read my update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are functions. That's why you get a function in the console. Call the rete function to get its value:

```
viewmodel.rete();
```

Also see the [Knockout: Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) help topic that describes this (under "Reading and writing observables").

This is how you can obtain a new value. Then, you need to update the dependent lookup data source. For this, make the *is_impiantiSource* property an observable array:

```
is_impiantiSource: ko.observableArray(OverviewAPP.listaImpianti),
```

After this, modify it in setRene like:

```
viewModel.is_impiantiSource(OverviewAPP.listaImpianti)
```

Also see [Observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) for how to work with arrays in Knockout

Comment: thanks for the answer. Meanwhile, I've done it in another way and it works. Can you read my update?

Comment: If you handle the onSelectionChanged event. It does not have the *e.value* parameter: http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxLookup/Configuration/?version=15_2#onSelectionChanged

Comment: Maybe, you handle the *onValueChanged* event (http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxLookup/Configuration/?version=15_2#onValueChanged)?

Comment: I can read correctly the selected value. But how can I update the second binded list? it is empty and I have to populate it as it needs after the selection on the first list

Comment: Is OverviewAPP.listaImpianti an array? If so, just call *viewModel.is_impiantiSource(OverviewAPP.listaImpianti)*

Comment: I get this: viewModel.is_impiantiSource is not a function', why?

Comment: This is the definition: OverviewAPP.listaImpianti = [];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104878/discussion-between-gosha-fighten-and-piero-alberto).